# Reproduce the gmail windows shortcuts

Tags: jquery, html, keyevent, intercept

I look to reproduce the gmail shortcuts behavior in my HTML application.
If you press ? ou shift+/ (or shift+, on azerty keyboard) a hidden div appear with a shortcuts list.
(If you are in a input, the key event as not intercepted).

I search to intercept correctly the keydown with jquery to show the div.
On my case, the keydown is intercepted on all component of my page.

How to disable the keyevent on others HTML component ?
I tried with `e.stopPropagation();` but this has not effect.

**Edit :**
I found this code,but not functionally on IE7

```
        $("input, textarea").keydown(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });


        function close_help(){
             $("#help:even").addClass("aou");
        }

        function doKeyDown(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 188) {
                $("#help:even").removeClass("aou");
            }

        }

        var input_ = document.getElementsByTagName("input").elements;

        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9) {
            window.attachEvent("keydown", doKeyDown, true);
        }
        else {
            window.addEventListener("keydown", doKeyDown, false);
        }
        input_.removeEventListener("keydown");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check

> e.target.type

to see if you are in a input or other part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the propagation of an event you need to check three functions

1. [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
2. [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)
3. [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)

The last one is needed when you have multiple events on the same DOM level as the one you want to handle.